# Работа со отображением

Tags: java

Почему не работает такой код и как сделать, чтобы заработал ?

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>  ipHost  = new HashMap<>();

for (String host : hosts) { // hosts is ArrayList<String>
    String ip = getIpByHost(host); // getIpByHost - my method
    if (ipHost.containsKey(ip)) {
        ipHost.put(ip, ipHost.get(ip).add(host)); // no suitable method found for put(java.lang.String,boolean)
    } else {
        ipHost.put(ip, new ArrayList<String>());
        ipHost.put(ip, ipHost.get(ip).add(host));
    }
}

return ipHost;
```

Comment: Я предполагаю это из-за того, что метод put помещает в HashMap уникальное значение ключа (ip), а вы его как  раз там и ищите. Нужно именно изменять конкретный этемент, а не опмещать новый.

Comment: Нет, вру, эта конструкция валидная

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-

Метод add возвращает boolean значение. Соответсвенно Вы пытаетесь положить значение `boolean` в `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, `HashMap` ожидает, что переменная будет `ArrayList<String>`

Перепишите блок:

```
if (ipHost.containsKey(ip)) {
   List<String> ipList = ipHost.get(ip)
   ipList.add(host)
   ipHost.put(ip, ipList)
}
```

Блок else тоже содержит ошибку.

```
    List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ipList.add(host);
    ipHost.put(ip, ipList);
```

В результате у меня получился такой код:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>  ipHost  = new HashMap<>();

for (String host : hosts) { // hosts is ArrayList<String>
    String ip = getIpByHost(host); // getIpByHost - my method
    if (ipHost.containsKey(ip)) {
        List<String> ipList = ipHost.get(ip);
        ipList.add(host); 
        ipHost.put(ip, ipList );
    } else {
        List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ipList.add(host);
        ipHost.put(ip, ipList);
    }
}

return ipHost;
```

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо. Не понятно только одно. Разве выражением `List<String> ipList = ipHost.get(ip);` мы берем не ссылку на объект ? Ведь тогда по сути строка `ipHost.put(ip, ipList );` не нужна, разве нет ?

Comment: Да все верно. Получается если у нас есть ArrayList то можно ограничиться кодом: `ipHost.get(ip).add(host)` (и мы сэкономим пару тактов из-за того, что не будем делать Map#put(). Но мне кажется, что делая put код получается чуточку понятнее.

Comment: Хотя спустя 2 минуты мне уже кажется, что `ipHost.get(ip).add(host)` будет лучше, чем то, что я написал. Но тут уже на усмотрение автора:)

Comment: Я сразу после того как понял в чем дело написал `ipHost.get(ip).add(host)`.